# iOS Safari Web Extension - What happens to current users when we add a new required permission

Tags: ios, web, safari, permissions, web-extension

I'm working on an iOS Safari Web Extension, and I want to add a new required permission.

However, I can't find anywhere explaining what happens for the current users.

- Will the extension continue to work as previously?
- Will the extension be disabled until the user activates again?

From our tests, it seems that everything works as expected.

We want to add the nativeMessaging permission.

Does anyone know if Apple has that information anywhere? Or what will happen?

Comment: I would imagine that the extension would behave as if the user had not granted the new permission until the permission is requested. After that point the behaviour of the extension will depend on whether the user granted the permission or not.

Comment: From our tests, installing an update from Testflight, the extension continues to work and the message (our case) is sent from the extension correctly and caught in `SafariWebExtensionHandler`. But I agree with the behavior that you described, seems like the best approach for the user and for the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Apple Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/692239?answerId=691284022&replyId=691284022), an engineer replied:

> Yes, adding new permissions has no impact on existing users. New host
> permissions will need the user to allow them when the extension next
> tries to access tabs, cookies, pages, etc that match the new host
> patterns.